# Fix the KeycloakConfigResolver for Springboot 2.6.xxx

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌──->──┐
|  resourceServerConfig (field private org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.keycloakConfigResolver)
└──<-──┘
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver as separate configuration outside the spring security class

```
 @Configuration
 public class KeycloakConfiguration {
 @Bean
 public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
    return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
 }
}
```

Comment: The spring version 2.6 support the keycloak config resolver as a separate configuration